# OpenGL Lighting on texture plane is not working

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, lighting, opengl-compat

I want to light to the texture plane but this is not work. Light on solid sphere is very well, but texture plane is not light.

[Whole Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBRgP.jpg)
[image]

Lighting on solid-sphere is working well.
[image]

But, lighting on texture plane is not working. (GL_DECAL, GL_REPLACE; I also tried GL_MODULATE)
[image]

This is a snippet of my rendering code. ([Whole code on GitHub](https://github.com/rollrat/low-engine/tree/error/low-engine))

Loading texture.

```
  sf::Image image;

  if (!image.loadFromFile(path))
    return false;
  glGenTextures(1, &id);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);

  glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,
    image.getSize().x, image.getSize().y, 0,
    GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    image.getPixelsPtr()
  );

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

Initialize

```
  glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
  glClearDepth(1.0f);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
  glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
  //glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
  glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
  glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
  glutSetCursor(GLUT_CURSOR_NONE);
  light.Init();

  camera.SetPin((GLfloat)width / 2, (GLfloat)height/2);
```

Display Callback

```
  adjustPerspective();

  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

  glPushMatrix();
  camera.SetLookAt();
  light.On();

  // TODO: dsiplay processing
  for (auto& obj : display_objs)
  {
    glPushMatrix();
    obj->Draw();
    glPopMatrix();
  }
  glPopMatrix();

  // print fps and swap buffers
```

Light Initialize Function

```
  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
  glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
  glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
  glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

  // Set lighting intensity and color
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, qaAmbientLight);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, qaDiffuseLight);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, qaLightPosition);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, qaSpecularLight);
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////

  glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 80.0);// set cutoff angle
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, dirVector0);
  glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, 10.0); // set focusing strength
```

Light.On() Function

```
  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(2.0, 10.0, 2.0);
  //glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, qaLightPosition);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, dirVector0);
  glPopMatrix();

  glPushMatrix();
  glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
  glTranslatef(2.0, 0.0, 2.0);
  glRotatef(-90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glutWireCone(tan(80.0 / 180.0 * 3.14159265),10.0,20,20);
  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
  glPopMatrix();
```

And this is texture plane draw function.

```
  float tile_x = 0.125;

  glTranslatef(x, y, z);

  glEnable(GL_BLEND);
  glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex.GetId());
  glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    // Both of the following cases not work.
    glNormal3f(0, -1, 0);
    glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(height*tile_x, 0.0); glVertex3f(0, 0, width);
    glTexCoord2f(height*tile_x, width*tile_x); glVertex3f(height, 0, width);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, width*tile_x); glVertex3f(height, 0, 0);
  glEnd();

  glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

I changed the vector direction, changed the `glTexEnvf` attribute, changed the order of the code, but did not fix the error. I think there is a fundamental error in my code, but I can not find it. Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Could the normal of the plane be pointing to the wrong direction? I'm not sure what the -1 or 1 of the command `glNormal3f(0, -1 or 1, 0);` does.

Comment: That means `glNormal3f(0, -1, 0);` or `glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);`. I am sorry for the ambiguous expression.

Comment: Does the light illuminate the plane if it doesn't have a texture?

Comment: Oh, no. this is not work too.

Comment: To me that would point to a problem on how you are declaring the vertexes of the geometry of the plane.

I'm very rusty on my OpenGL, but I seem to remember that the vertexes of some geometry had to be declared on a certain order. Maybe reverse the order you're using to declare the vertexes?

Comment: glNormal3f(~, ~, ~); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0); glVertex3f(0, 0, width); glVertex3f(height, 0, width); glVertex3f(height, 0, 0); This is vertexes of plane. Whole code is just in asked, last of snippet codes.

Comment: I did reverse the vertexes order, but also not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to light to the texture plane but this is not work. Light on solid sphere is very well, but texture plane is not light.

This is an issue caused by the [Gouraud Shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading) model of the OpenGLs standard light model. While [Phong shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading) in common means the technique, which does the light calculations per fragment, at [Gouraud Shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading), the light calculations are done per vertex. The calculated light is interpolated according to the [Barycentric coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) of the fragment on the primitive.

This means that in your case the light is calculated for the corners of the ground quad. This so calculated light is interpolated for all the fragments in between. The angel of the normal vector at the corners to the light vector tends to 90°. Because of that the entire ground quad looks almost unlit.

Since the light is calculated per vertex, then the light is calculated for more positions than the the 4 corners of the quad and the quality increases. Note, the light on the spheres looks almost perfect, because a sphere consists of a lot of vertices around its shape.

Try the following code, which splits the quad into tiles:

```
int   tiles = 5;
float u_max = height*tile_x;
float v_max = width*tile_x

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glNormal3f(0, 1, 0);

for (int x=0; x < tiles; ++x)
{
    for (int y=0; y < tiles; ++y)
    {
        x0 = (float)x/(float)tiles;
        x1 = (float)(x+1)/(float)tiles;
        y0 = (float)y/(float)tiles;
        y1 = (float)(y+1)/(float)tiles;

        glTexCoord2f(u_max*x0, v_max*y0);  glVertex3f(height*x0, 0, widht*y0);
        glTexCoord2f(u_max*x1, v_max*y0);  glVertex3f(height*x0, 0, widht*y1);
        glTexCoord2f(u_max*x1, v_max*y1);  glVertex3f(height*x1, 0, widht*y1);
        glTexCoord2f(u_max*x0, v_max*y1);  glVertex3f(height*x1, 0, widht*y0);
    }
}
glEnd();
```

Of course you can also write your own shader and implement per fragment lighting. But the deprecated fixed function pipeline OpenGL standard light model does not support per fragment lighting.

See the difference in the WebGL example:

```js
(function loadscene() {

var resize, gl, gouraudDraw, phongDraw, vp_size;
var bufSphere = {};

function render(delteMS){

    var shading = document.getElementById( "shading" ).value;
    var shininess = document.getElementById( "shininess" ).value;
    var ambientCol = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2];
    var diffuseCol = [0.6, 0.6, 0.6];
    var specularCol = [0.8, 0.8, 0.8];

    Camera.create();
    Camera.vp = vp_size;
        
    gl.enable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );
    gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    gl.disable(gl.CULL_FACE);
    
    
    var progDraw = shading == 0 ? gouraudDraw : phongDraw;;
    // set up draw shader
    ShaderProgram.Use( progDraw.prog );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformM44( progDraw.prog, "u_projectionMat44", Camera.Perspective() );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformM44( progDraw.prog, "u_viewMat44", Camera.LookAt() );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformF3( progDraw.prog, "u_lightSource.lightPos", [0.0, 0.0, 0.25] )
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformF3( progDraw.prog, "u_lightSource.ambient", ambientCol )
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformF3( progDraw.prog, "u_lightSource.diffuse", diffuseCol )
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformF3( progDraw.prog, "u_lightSource.specular", specularCol )
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformF1( progDraw.prog, "u_lightSource.shininess", shininess )
    var modelMat = IdentityMat44()
    modelMat = RotateAxis( modelMat, -1.5, 0 );
    modelMat = RotateAxis( modelMat, CalcAng( delteMS, 17.0 ), 1 );
    ShaderProgram.SetUniformM44( progDraw.prog, "u_modelMat44", modelMat );
    
    // draw scene
    VertexBuffer.Draw( bufSphere );
   
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function resize() {
    //vp_size = [gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight];
    vp_size = [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight]
    canvas.width = vp_size[0];
    canvas.height = vp_size[1];
    gl.viewport( 0, 0, vp_size[0], vp_size[1] );
}

function initScene() {

    canvas = document.getElementById( "canvas");
    gl = canvas.getContext( "experimental-webgl" );
    if ( !gl )
      return null;

    gouraudDraw = {}
    gouraudDraw.prog = ShaderProgram.Create( 
      [ { source : "gouraud-shader-vs", stage : gl.VERTEX_SHADER },
        { source : "gouraud-shader-fs", stage : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER }
      ],
      [ "u_projectionMat44", "u_viewMat44", "u_modelMat44", 
        "u_lightSource.lightDir", "u_lightSource.ambient", "u_lightSource.diffuse", "u_lightSource.specular", "u_lightSource.shininess", ] );
    if ( gouraudDraw.prog == 0 )
      return;  
    gouraudDraw.inPos = gl.getAttribLocation( gouraudDraw.prog, "inPos" );
    gouraudDraw.inNV  = gl.getAttribLocation( gouraudDraw.prog, "inNV" );
    gouraudDraw.inCol = gl.getAttribLocation( gouraudDraw.prog, "inCol" );

    phongDraw = {}
    phongDraw.prog = ShaderProgram.Create( 
      [ { source : "phong-shader-vs", stage : gl.VERTEX_SHADER },
        { source : "phong-shader-fs", stage : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER }
      ],
      [ "u_projectionMat44", "u_viewMat44", "u_modelMat44", 
        "u_lightSource.lightDir", "u_lightSource.ambient", "u_lightSource.diffuse", "u_lightSource.specular", "u_lightSource.shininess", ] );
    if ( phongDraw.prog == 0 )
      return;
    phongDraw.inPos = gl.getAttribLocation( phongDraw.prog, "inPos" );
    phongDraw.inNV  = gl.getAttribLocation( phongDraw.prog, "inNV" );
    phongDraw.inCol = gl.getAttribLocation( phongDraw.prog, "inCol" );
    
    // create cube
    var layer_size = 16, circum_size = 32;
    var rad_circum = 1.0;
    var rad_tube = 0.5;
    var sphere_pts = [-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0];
    var sphere_nv  = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0];
    var sphere_col = [0.8, 0.6, 0.3, 0.8, 0.6, 0.3, 0.8, 0.6, 0.3, 0.8, 0.6, 0.3];
    var sphere_inx = [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3];
    bufSphere = VertexBuffer.Create(
    [ { data : sphere_pts, attrSize : 3, attrLoc : gouraudDraw.inPos },
      { data : sphere_nv, attrSize : 3, attrLoc : gouraudDraw.inNV },
      { data : sphere_col, attrSize : 3, attrLoc : gouraudDraw.inCol } ],
      sphere_inx );
      
    window.onresize = resize;
    resize();
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function Fract( val ) { 
    return val - Math.trunc( val );
}
function CalcAng( deltaTime, intervall ) {
    return Fract( deltaTime / (1000*intervall) ) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
}
function CalcMove( deltaTime, intervall, range ) {
    var pos = self.Fract( deltaTime / (1000*intervall) ) * 2.0
    var pos = pos < 1.0 ? pos : (2.0-pos)
    return range[0] + (range[1] - range[0]) * pos;
}    
function EllipticalPosition( a, b, angRag ) {
    var a_b = a * a - b * b
    var ea = (a_b <= 0) ? 0 : Math.sqrt( a_b );
    var eb = (a_b >= 0) ? 0 : Math.sqrt( -a_b );
    return [ a * Math.sin( angRag ) - ea, b * Math.cos( angRag ) - eb, 0 ];
}

glArrayType = typeof Float32Array !="undefined" ? Float32Array : ( typeof WebGLFloatArray != "undefined" ? WebGLFloatArray : Array );

function IdentityMat44() {
  var m = new glArrayType(16);
  m[0]  = 1; m[1]  = 0; m[2]  = 0; m[3]  = 0;
  m[4]  = 0; m[5]  = 1; m[6]  = 0; m[7]  = 0;
  m[8]  = 0; m[9]  = 0; m[10] = 1; m[11] = 0;
  m[12] = 0; m[13] = 0; m[14] = 0; m[15] = 1;
  return m;
};

function RotateAxis(matA, angRad, axis) {
    var aMap = [ [1, 2], [2, 0], [0, 1] ];
    var a0 = aMap[axis][0], a1 = aMap[axis][1]; 
    var sinAng = Math.sin(angRad), cosAng = Math.cos(angRad);
    var matB = new glArrayType(16);
    for ( var i = 0; i < 16; ++ i ) matB[i] = matA[i];
    for ( var i = 0; i < 3; ++ i ) {
        matB[a0*4+i] = matA[a0*4+i] * cosAng + matA[a1*4+i] * sinAng;
        matB[a1*4+i] = matA[a0*4+i] * -sinAng + matA[a1*4+i] * cosAng;
    }
    return matB;
}

function Cross( a, b ) { return [ a[1] * b[2] - a[2] * b[1], a[2] * b[0] - a[0] * b[2], a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0], 0.0 ]; }
function Dot( a, b ) { return a[0]*b[0] + a[1]*b[1] + a[2]*b[2]; }
function Normalize( v ) {
    var len = Math.sqrt( v[0] * v[0] + v[1] * v[1] + v[2] * v[2] );
    return [ v[0] / len, v[1] / len, v[2] / len ];
}

var Camera = {};
Camera.create = function() {
    this.pos    = [0, 2, 0.0];
    this.target = [0, 0, 0];
    this.up     = [0, 0, 1];
    this.fov_y  = 90;
    this.vp     = [800, 600];
    this.near   = 0.5;
    this.far    = 100.0;
}
Camera.Perspective = function() {
    var fn = this.far + this.near;
    var f_n = this.far - this.near;
    var r = this.vp[0] / this.vp[1];
    var t = 1 / Math.tan( Math.PI * this.fov_y / 360 );
    var m = IdentityMat44();
    m[0]  = t/r; m[1]  = 0; m[2]  =  0;                              m[3]  = 0;
    m[4]  = 0;   m[5]  = t; m[6]  =  0;                              m[7]  = 0;
    m[8]  = 0;   m[9]  = 0; m[10] = -fn / f_n;                       m[11] = -1;
    m[12] = 0;   m[13] = 0; m[14] = -2 * this.far * this.near / f_n; m[15] =  0;
    return m;
}
Camera.LookAt = function() {
    var mz = Normalize( [ this.pos[0]-this.target[0], this.pos[1]-this.target[1], this.pos[2]-this.target[2] ] );
    var mx = Normalize( Cross( this.up, mz ) );
    var my = Normalize( Cross( mz, mx ) );
    var tx = Dot( mx, this.pos );
    var ty = Dot( my, this.pos );
    var tz = Dot( [-mz[0], -mz[1], -mz[2]], this.pos ); 
    var m = IdentityMat44();
    m[0]  = mx[0]; m[1]  = my[0]; m[2]  = mz[0]; m[3]  = 0;
    m[4]  = mx[1]; m[5]  = my[1]; m[6]  = mz[1]; m[7]  = 0;
    m[8]  = mx[2]; m[9]  = my[2]; m[10] = mz[2]; m[11] = 0;
    m[12] = tx;    m[13] = ty;    m[14] = tz;    m[15] = 1; 
    return m;
} 

var ShaderProgram = {};
ShaderProgram.Create = function( shaderList ) {
    var shaderObjs = [];
    for ( var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderList.length; ++ i_sh ) {
        var shderObj = this.CompileShader( shaderList[i_sh].source, shaderList[i_sh].stage );
        if ( shderObj == 0 )
            return 0;
        shaderObjs.push( shderObj );
    }
    var progObj = this.LinkProgram( shaderObjs )
    if ( progObj != 0 ) {
        progObj.attribIndex = {};
        var noOfAttributes = gl.getProgramParameter( progObj, gl.ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES );
        for ( var i_n = 0; i_n < noOfAttributes; ++ i_n ) {
            var name = gl.getActiveAttrib( progObj, i_n ).name;
            progObj.attribIndex[name] = gl.getAttribLocation( progObj, name );
        }
        progObj.unifomLocation = {};
        var noOfUniforms = gl.getProgramParameter( progObj, gl.ACTIVE_UNIFORMS );
        for ( var i_n = 0; i_n < noOfUniforms; ++ i_n ) {
            var name = gl.getActiveUniform( progObj, i_n ).name;
            progObj.unifomLocation[name] = gl.getUniformLocation( progObj, name );
        }
    }
    return progObj;
}
ShaderProgram.AttributeIndex = function( progObj, name ) { return progObj.attribIndex[name]; } 
ShaderProgram.UniformLocation = function( progObj, name ) { return progObj.unifomLocation[name]; } 
ShaderProgram.Use = function( progObj ) { gl.useProgram( progObj ); } 
ShaderProgram.SetUniformI1  = function( progObj, name, val ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform1i( progObj.unifomLocation[name], val ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformF1  = function( progObj, name, val ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform1f( progObj.unifomLocation[name], val ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformF2  = function( progObj, name, arr ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform2fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], arr ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformF3  = function( progObj, name, arr ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform3fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], arr ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformF4  = function( progObj, name, arr ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniform4fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], arr ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformM33 = function( progObj, name, mat ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniformMatrix3fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], false, mat ); }
ShaderProgram.SetUniformM44 = function( progObj, name, mat ) { if(progObj.unifomLocation[name]) gl.uniformMatrix4fv( progObj.unifomLocation[name], false, mat ); }
ShaderProgram.CompileShader = function( source, shaderStage ) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(source);
    if (shaderScript)
      source = shaderScript.text;
    var shaderObj = gl.createShader( shaderStage );
    gl.shaderSource( shaderObj, source );
    gl.compileShader( shaderObj );
    var status = gl.getShaderParameter( shaderObj, gl.COMPILE_STATUS );
    if ( !status ) alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shaderObj));
    return status ? shaderObj : null;
} 
ShaderProgram.LinkProgram = function( shaderObjs ) {
    var prog = gl.createProgram();
    for ( var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderObjs.length; ++ i_sh )
        gl.attachShader( prog, shaderObjs[i_sh] );
    gl.linkProgram( prog );
    status = gl.getProgramParameter( prog, gl.LINK_STATUS );
    if ( !status ) alert("Could not initialise shaders");
    gl.useProgram( null );
    return status ? prog : null;
}

var VertexBuffer = {};
VertexBuffer.Create = function( attributes, indices ) {
    var buffer = {};
    buffer.buf = [];
    buffer.attr = []
    for ( var i = 0; i < attributes.length; ++ i ) {
        buffer.buf.push( gl.createBuffer() );
        buffer.attr.push( { size : attributes[i].attrSize, loc : attributes[i].attrLoc } );
        gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.buf[i] );
        gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( attributes[i].data ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    }
    buffer.inx = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.inx );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array( indices ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    buffer.inxLen = indices.length;
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
    return buffer;
}
VertexBuffer.Draw = function( bufObj ) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < bufObj.buf.length; ++ i ) {
        gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.buf[i] );
        gl.vertexAttribPointer( bufObj.attr[i].loc, bufObj.attr[i].size, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray( bufObj.attr[i].loc );
    }
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.inx );
    gl.drawElements( gl.TRIANGLES, bufObj.inxLen, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
    for ( var i = 0; i < bufObj.buf.length; ++ i )
       gl.disableVertexAttribArray( bufObj.attr[i].loc );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
}

initScene();

})();
```

```css
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#gui {
    position : absolute;
    top : 0;
    left : 0;
}
```

```html
<script id="gouraud-shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  precision mediump float;
  
  attribute vec3 inPos;
  attribute vec3 inNV;
  attribute vec3 inCol;
  
  varying vec3 vertPos;
  varying vec3 vertNV;
  varying vec3 vertCol;
  
  uniform mat4 u_projectionMat44;
  uniform mat4 u_viewMat44;
  uniform mat4 u_modelMat44;

  struct TLightSource
  {
      vec3  lightPos;
      vec3  ambient;
      vec3  diffuse;
      vec3  specular;
      float shininess;
  };

  uniform TLightSource u_lightSource;
  
  vec3 Light( vec3 eyeV, vec3 N, vec3 P )
  {
      vec3  lightCol  = u_lightSource.ambient;
      vec3  L         = normalize( u_lightSource.lightPos-P );
      float NdotL     = max( 0.0, dot( N, L ) );
      lightCol       += NdotL * u_lightSource.diffuse;
      vec3  H         = normalize( eyeV + L );
      float NdotH     = max( 0.0, dot( N, H ) );
      float kSpecular = ( u_lightSource.shininess + 2.0 ) * pow( NdotH, u_lightSource.shininess ) / ( 2.0 * 3.14159265 );
      lightCol       += kSpecular * u_lightSource.specular;
      return lightCol; 
  }
  
  void main()
  {
      vec3 modelNV  = mat3( u_modelMat44 ) * normalize( inNV );
      vertNV        = mat3( u_viewMat44 ) * modelNV;
      vec4 modelPos = u_modelMat44 * vec4( inPos, 1.0 );
      vec4 viewPos  = u_viewMat44 * modelPos;
      vertPos       = viewPos.xyz / viewPos.w;
      vec3 eyeV     = normalize( -vertPos );
      vec3 normalV  = normalize( vertNV ) * sign(vertNV.z);
      vertCol       = inCol * Light( eyeV, normalV, vertPos );
      gl_Position   = u_projectionMat44 * viewPos;
  }
  </script>
  
  <script id="gouraud-shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  precision mediump float;
  
  varying vec3 vertPos;
  varying vec3 vertNV;
  varying vec3 vertCol;
  
  void main()
  {
      gl_FragColor = vec4( vertCol, 1.0 );
  }
  </script>

<script id="phong-shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
precision mediump float;

attribute vec3 inPos;
attribute vec3 inNV;
attribute vec3 inCol;

varying vec3 vertPos;
varying vec3 vertNV;
varying vec3 vertCol;

uniform mat4 u_projectionMat44;
uniform mat4 u_viewMat44;
uniform mat4 u_modelMat44;

void main()
{
  vec3 modelNV  = mat3( u_modelMat44 ) * normalize( inNV );
  vertNV        = mat3( u_viewMat44 ) * modelNV;
  vertCol       = inCol;
  vec4 modelPos = u_modelMat44 * vec4( inPos, 1.0 );
  vec4 viewPos  = u_viewMat44 * modelPos;
  vertPos       = viewPos.xyz / viewPos.w;
  gl_Position   = u_projectionMat44 * viewPos;
}
</script>

<script id="phong-shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 vertPos;
varying vec3 vertNV;
varying vec3 vertCol;

struct TLightSource
{
  vec3  lightPos;
  vec3  ambient;
  vec3  diffuse;
  vec3  specular;
  float shininess;
};

uniform TLightSource u_lightSource;

vec3 Light( vec3 eyeV, vec3 N, vec3 P )
{
  vec3  lightCol  = u_lightSource.ambient;
  vec3  L         = normalize( u_lightSource.lightPos - P );
  float NdotL     = max( 0.0, dot( N, L ) );
  lightCol       += NdotL * u_lightSource.diffuse;
  vec3  H         = normalize( eyeV + L );
  float NdotH     = max( 0.0, dot( N, H ) );
  float kSpecular = ( u_lightSource.shininess + 2.0 ) * pow( NdotH, u_lightSource.shininess ) / ( 2.0 * 3.14159265 );
  lightCol       += kSpecular * u_lightSource.specular;
  return lightCol; 
}

void main()
{
  vec3 eyeV    = normalize( -vertPos );
  vec3 normalV = normalize( vertNV ) * sign(vertNV.z);
  vec3 color   = vertCol * Light( eyeV, normalV, vertPos );
  gl_FragColor = vec4( color, 1.0 );
}
</script>

<form id="gui" name="inputs"><table><tr>
    <td><font color= #CCF>Shading:</font></td> 
    <td><select id="shading">>
        <option value="0">Gouraud</option>
        <option value="1">Phong</option>
    </select></td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td><font color= #CCF>Shininess:</font></td>
    <td><input type="range" id="shininess" min="0" max="100" value="10"/></td>
</tr></table></form>
<canvas id="canvas" style="border: none;" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
```